# Control not visible even visibility set to visible

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I am creating a window, in which click on save communicate with database and save data in database. I want to show progress image on click on save until data is not saved in database. I have set the visibility of image to true but still that progress image is not visible.

I have done following code...

In xml file..

```
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_Comment" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLength="5000"  Margin="2,2,2,0"></TextBox>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,-15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btn_Ok" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btn_Save_Click"  Height="25" Width="55">Save</Button>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Cancel" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="25" Width="55" Content="Cancel" Click="btn_Cancel_Click" >
        </Button>
    </WrapPanel>

    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Black" Opacity="0.25" Name="LoadingAdorner" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Border Width="400" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Opacity="1" Height="180" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" CornerRadius="2" x:Name="loaderBorder">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0" >
                <GradientStop Color="#EBF6FA" Offset="0.3"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#b7d9e5" Offset="1.0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Color="#FFB0B0B0" ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="95"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Controls:LoadingAnimation Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" LoadingText="Loading..."  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#647883" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2" Text="Saving..."></TextBlock>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

In code behind page..

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender1, DoWorkEventArgs e1)
{
    CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Comment.Text))
            {
                LoadingAdorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                loaderBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                using (Entities DB = new Entities(settings.LinqConnection))
                 {
                    if (txt_Comment.Text.Length > 1000)
                    {//In this case loading image is visible
                        MessageBox.Show("Comment is too large.", "Alert !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                        return;
                    }

                    var comment = DB.Table1.Create();//Here loading image is not visible.
                    comment.value = txt_Comment.Text;
                    comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
                    comment.ModifiedBy = settings.CurrentUID;
                    DB.Table1.Add(comment);

                    DB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }),
    DispatcherPriority.Normal);
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
    this.Close();
    LoadingAdorner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    loaderBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

When messagebox is visible than loading image is visible, but when data is saving in database then loading image is not visible.

Comment: I don't see any multi-threading going on here...how do you expect the UI to be responsive while the DB operation is happening?

Comment: I have added the threading part also in code..

Comment: Your whole work is routed back to the UI thread via `CurrentDispatcher.Invoke`. That's a convoluted way to say *"Please freeze my UI while the action is in progress"*

Comment: @Deepakgupta what do you  mean by that?

Comment: @rory.ap When message is visible than loading image is visible on window, but not when db operation is performing..

Comment: Your `RunWorkerCompleted` should use `CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` and that is the only part to use the Dispatcher! And try to look into MvvM. **All of this would be gone if you would use MvvM!**.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `using` block out of `CurrentDispatcher.Invoke()` and put after this call.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
        worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender1, DoWorkEventArgs e1)
        {
            CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
                                 new Action(() =>
                                 {
                                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Comment.Text))
                                     {
                                         LoadingAdorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                                         loaderBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                                         
                                     }
                                 }),
                                 DispatcherPriority.Normal);

                                 using (Entities DB = new Entities(settings.LinqConnection))
                                         {
                                             if (txt_Comment.Text.Length > 1000)
                                             {//In this case loading image is visible

                                                 MessageBox.Show("Comment is too large.", "Alert !", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                                                 return;
                                             }

                                             var comment = DB.Table1.Create();//Here loading image is not visible.
                                             comment.value = txt_Comment.Text;
                                             comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
                                             comment.ModifiedBy = settings.CurrentUID;
                                             DB.Table1.Add(comment);

                                             DB.SaveChanges();
                                         }
        };
```

so this code works for me:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };
    worker.DoWork += delegate (object sender1, DoWorkEventArgs e1)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
                             new Action(() =>{testCtl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;}),
                             System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        testCtl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: @Deepakgupta while it works, I don't see the benefit in setting the `Visibility.Visible` inside the background task when it starts executing, instead of setting it as soon as the user clicked the button... the user typically wants to know that his input was received and will be processed rather than being informed about the technical details (exact starting time of task execution)

Comment: Moving 'using' block outside CurrentDispatcher.Invoke() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would have done in such situation :

Create delegate to update your visibility and corresponding method

Wrap your anonymous function in a function compatible with doWork event

Create a new delegate and call the update method using dispatcher.BeginInvoke() when you need to update visibility.

```
    private delegate void UpdateVisibilityDelegate(Visibility visibility);

    private void UpdateVisiblity(Visibility visibility)
    {
        //LoadingAdorner.Visibility = visibility;
        //loaderBorder.Visibility = visibility;
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your Action() code here
        // Change the visibility using this method
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new UpdateVisibilityDelegate(this.UpdateVisiblity), Visibility.Visible);

    }
```